# Symfony 2 with Doctrine 2 Single Table Inheritance

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, yaml, single-table-inheritance

In my project based on Symfony 2 + Doctrine 2 I implement model with following approach (based on FOSUserBundle source code):

1. All classes which belong to model are in "Model" folder of my bundle
2. In "Entity" folder I have classes which extend classes from Model
3. In "Resources/config/doctrine/" I have files with mappings in YAML format

**Important:** Classes for persistance (Entities) for which I want STI extend respective classes from Model, not from Entity.

The problem:

```
#Resources/config/doctrine/ContentElement.orm.yml
My\CoreBundle\Entity\ContentElement:
    type: entity
    table: content_element 
    inheritanceType: SINGLE_TABLE
    discriminatorColumn:
        name: discr 
        type: string
        length: 255
    discriminatorMap: 
        contentElement: ContentElementList
        htmlContentElement: HtmlContentElement
    id:   
        id:   
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    fields:
        anchor_id:
            type: string
        anchor_text:
            type: string

#Resources/config/doctrine/HtmlContentElement.orm.yml
My\CoreBundle\Entity\HtmlContentElement:
    type: entity
    fields:
        html: 
            type: text
```

When I try to update database I've got errors from YAML driver until I specify additionally 'id' (which should be inherited as I thought)

After adding mapping for id I have sql queries in which I see 2 separate tables for each entity.

I suspect that this happens because HtmlContentElement extends Model\HtmlContentElement but not Entity\ContentElement.

Am I right and is there known solution to my problem?

Comment: You must extend the class you're trying to inherit from, there's no way around that. I will not post this as an answer because I question the implementation of the model concept and I do not know why you'd need that. Maybe if you explain your main problem or why you did that we could find a way around it, but that's definitely not the way entities are suppposed to be.